# Convert Buffer to file object for posting

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am attempting to POST an image that is in the format of Buffer to an endpoint that expects an image from a fs object using NODE.

Here is the code that works:

```
const request = require("request")
const fs = require("fs")
image_stream = fs.createReadStream("test-image3.jpg")
var form = {"image":image_stream}
request.post({url:".....", formData:form}
```

Here is what I have:

```
    @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  async create(@UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File) {

    const FormData = require('form-data');
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('image', image.buffer);
    const response = await this.httpService.post('...',
      bodyFormData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
```

I am receiving the error: "The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Readable" There sadly is nothing on this on google

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) to avoid that error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33471498)